# Can't start/open an activity when expandable listview item/child clicked

Tags: android

Hi I want the child in my expandable listview to start a new activity can someone please show me where I am going wrong.  I've tried to do this but the code I am using kills the app once I click any of the childviews.  I've added my adapter code as per the request. Thanks.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener, View.OnClickLis``tener {


    String[] searches = {"Height", "Weight", "Hair Colour"};
    List<String> childList;
    List<String> groupList;

    Map<String, List<String>> advSearchOption;
    ExpandableListView expListView;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        createGroupList();

        createCollection();

        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.search_list);
        final ExpandableListAdapter expListAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(
                this, groupList, advSearchOption);
        expListView.setAdapter(expListAdapter);

        expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

            Intent k;


            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                switch (childPosition){
                    case 0:
                        k = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ChildActivity.class);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        k = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ChildActivity.class);
                        break;
                }
                startActivity(k);
                return true;
            }





        });



    private void createGroupList() {
        groupList = new ArrayList<String>();
        groupList.add("Advanced Search");
    }

    private void createCollection() {
        // preparing laptops collection(child)
        String[] searches = {"Height", "Weight", "Hair Colour"};

        advSearchOption = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();

        for (String advSearch : groupList) {
            if (advSearch.equals("Advanced Search")) {
                loadChild(searches);
            }

            advSearchOption.put(advSearch, childList);
        }
    }


    private void loadChild(String[] searchOptions) {
        childList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String model : searchOptions)
            childList.add(model);
    }

    private void setGroupIndicatorToRight() {
        /* Get the screen width */
        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        int width = dm.widthPixels;

    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

package com.mycompany.testing;

public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

```
private Activity context;
private Map<String, List<String>> advSearchOptions;
private List<String> options;

public ExpandableListAdapter(Activity context, List<String> options,
                             Map<String, List<String>> advSearchOptions) {
    this.context = context;
    this.advSearchOptions = advSearchOptions;
    this.options = options;
}

public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return advSearchOptions.get(options.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
}

public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}


public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final String laptop = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_item, null);
    }

    TextView item = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.advSearch);


    item.setText(laptop);
    return convertView;
}

public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return advSearchOptions.get(options.get(groupPosition)).size();
}

public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return options.get(groupPosition);
}

public int getGroupCount() {
    return options.size();
}

public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String laptopName = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.group_item,
                null);
    }
    TextView item = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.advSearch);
    item.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    item.setText(laptopName);
    return convertView;
}

public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: `onChildClick` click event is happening when child item is clicked ?

Comment: Is there any error message you're getting or nothing happens at all? Could you provide logcat output

Comment: could You post Your adapter source code, please?

Comment: click event is firing ? assuming  activities are specified in manifest

Comment: Hi I have attached the adapter code I am using.  Im not getting any error messages the app is killed at the point I click any of the childviews